# get all months last days in mysql

Tags: mysql

For example I have a table with fields:

```
id     date
1      2001-01-01
2      2001-01-05
.................
N      2011-12-31
```

How get i get all months last days from this table?
example:

if i have dates like 2001-05-31 and 2001-06-01
i need only 2001-05-31 not both

Comment: The last day of the month like the 30th, 31st? Or the latest day entry for that month in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. but this query is very slow on large tables. so I am still looking for a better solution

```
select DISTINCT(LAST_DAY(date)) from table;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do `SELECT LAST_DAY` for example the below returns Oct. 31st. 2010

```
SELECT LAST_DAY('2010-10-10');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(date_format(date, '%d')) as last_day_of_the_month
from table
group by date_format(date, '%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would work better?

```
select DISTINCT(LAST_DAY(date)) from table GROUP BY date_format(date, '%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, date
FROM  `table` 
WHERE DATE( date ) = LAST_DAY( date )
```

The DATE function over field is for filter the date without time, use only if you have a datetime column.

The query get all rows with date = last day of month.

Answer (score 0):

```
select subdate(adddate(subdate(`date`, day(`date`) - 1), interval 1 month), 1)
```

Note: This is the "hard way". See @harper89's answer - it's better :)

Answer (score -1):

```
select max(date)
from table
group by year(date), month(date)
```

Comment: it will return maximum day value from month not the last day. if i have dates like 2001-05-31 and 2001-06-01 i need only first one